# Error while using How can os.path.abspath

Tags: python, os.path

How can I use os.path.abspath to access some file in my local directory directly

e.g

```
os.path.abspath(U:\Folder1\Folder2\takeThisFile.map)
```

Comment: Maybe with quotes, so that you pass a string to `os.path.abspath`?

Comment: What have you tried?  Why do you think you need abspath? Remember it just returns an absolutized version of the path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a string to os.path.abspath method. Also as you are using a backslash in the string you need to either escape it or use **r** flag to pass it as raw string, like this:

```
os.path.abspath(r'U:\Folder1\Folder2\takeThisFile.map')
```

or

```
os.path.abspath('U:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\takeThisFile.map')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add quotes:
os.path.abspath('U:\Folder1\Folder2\takeThisFile.map')